# Spring boot - Try to authenticate user from mySQL DB - A granted authority textual representation is required

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

2018-10-17 20:05:37.715 ERROR 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: A granted authority textual representation is required

Here is my **SecurityConfig**:

```
package com.project.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private MyAppUserDetailsService myAppUserDetailsService;    
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/app/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
    .and().formLogin()  //login configuration
            .loginPage("/app/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/app-login")
            .usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/secure/temployee-details") 
    .and().logout()    //logout configuration
    .logoutUrl("/app-logout") 
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/app/login")
    .and().exceptionHandling() //exception handling configuration
    .accessDeniedPage("/app/error");
} 
    @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
          auth.userDetailsService(myAppUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
}
```

And **UserDetailsService**:

```
package com.project.config;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.project.dao.IUserInfoDAO;
import com.project.entity.UserInfo;
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Service
public class MyAppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private IUserInfoDAO userInfoDAO;
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(),
            activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
}
```

**UserInfoDao**:

```
package com.project.dao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.project.entity.TEmployee;
import com.project.entity.UserInfo;
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserInfoDAO implements IUserInfoDAO {
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager;
public UserInfo getActiveUser(String userName) {
    UserInfo activeUserInfo = new UserInfo();
    short enabled = 1;
    List<?> list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserInfo u WHERE userName=?1 and enabled=?2")
            .setParameter(1, userName).setParameter(2, enabled).getResultList();
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        activeUserInfo = (UserInfo)list.get(0);
    }
    return activeUserInfo;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<TEmployee> getAllUserEmployees() {
    String hql = "FROM TEmployee as t ORDER BY t.employee_id";
    return (List<TEmployee>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
}   
}
```

I really don't understand why I still received A granted authority textual representation is required. 
I've added a proper role to the 'role' column in my database: `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER` and everything seems to be fine here.

Some logs:

> 2018-10-17 20:05:29.932  INFO 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2018-10-17 20:05:29.932  INFO
>   15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>   2018-10-17 20:05:29.938  INFO 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 6 ms 2018-10-17
>   20:05:37.694  INFO 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3]
>   o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using
>   ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 2018-10-17 20:05:37.701 DEBUG 15968 ---
>   [nio-8090-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
>       select
>           userinfo0_.userid as userid1_1_,
>           userinfo0_.enabled as enabled2_1_,
>           userinfo0_.password as password3_1_,
>           userinfo0_.role as role4_1_ 
>       from
>           tuserid userinfo0_ 
>       where
>           userinfo0_.userid=? 
>           and userinfo0_.enabled=? 2018-10-17 20:05:37.701 TRACE 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [kudelam] 2018-10-17 20:05:37.701
>   TRACE 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 
>   : binding parameter [2] as [SMALLINT] - [1] 2018-10-17 20:05:37.715
>   ERROR 15968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3]
>   w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred
>   while trying to authenticate the user.
>
> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException:
>   A granted authority textual representation is required

Could you please take a look and shred some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way instead of

```
GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(),
        activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
```

Do

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole()));


return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(activeUserInfo.getUsername(),
                                                              activeUserInfo.getPassword(),
                                                              grantedAuthorities);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately - error is still the same. When i try to log in i received "Bad credentials" and info from the logs:                                             
 2018-10-18 09:09:11.670 ERROR 17208 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: A granted authority textual representation is required

Comment: How are you storing the passwords?  If it is plaintext, then that is an issue.  You need to store encrypted format.

Comment: I stored encrypted format of password. I've used BCrypt online tool to encrypt my password: $2y$12$jpyWS0aIW7.jiMN.iAh81egdEfMZh3QlbS9LvoW/nmhFpS48n07y6